# SSH Listener not closing

Tags: networking, go, ssh

I'm trying to write a go application that would allow me to perform reverse ssh tunneling between a Windows machine and a Linux machine using the go ssh library.

In the process of doing so, I create a listener on the remote machine, as follows:

`remoteListener, err := sshClient.Listen("tcp", remoteString)`

where sshClient is an object of type ssh.Client and is configured to connect to the remote machine.

The issue here is that when the sshd process on the Linux machine disrupts the connection with the application, the ssh Listener remains alive on the remote machine. So, reconnecting with the application fails because a listener is already running on the same port on the remote machine.

How do I get around this issue? Does the ssh library allow me to define a timeout on the listener?

Comment: How are you closing the session to the remote machine? The ssh server should be cleaning up the connection if the session has been terminated. –

Comment: I'm testing ssh failure by blocking ssh connections on port 2222 (the port on which I'm ssh-ing) using the following command:
`sudo iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DROP`. This doesn't seem to clean up the terminated session.

Comment: If you're just dropping packets, the remote server has no way to know you've terminated the session.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just waiting for the timeout after reconnecting. I found no other easy solution for this.